How to toggle system taskbar icons with Windows API or any other API
My main goal is to disable the clock icon without editing regex and restarting Explorer (similarly to how the Windows Settings App achieves this).
I'd be grateful if anyone familiar with the Windows API or any other API that allows this could possibly explain to me the way to approach this problem.

There is no public Win32 API to manipulate the clock in the way you want.

Not an API, but you can do it programmatically sortof, using Windows UI Automation just like the end-user would do: you need to open the context menu, run "adjust date and time" and toggle "Show time and date in the system tray", as this is a switch that supports the Toggle Control Pattern

The settings app most likely writes to the registry and then sends WM_SETTINGSCHANGE. Process Monitor+Spy++ would tell you...

this is what i was looking for, thanks. i used cheat engine and saw some mem addresses that got changed everytime i flipped the clock setting but when i changed it myself it didnt update. would I send WM_SETTINGSCHANGE to explorer.exe when i change the memory?. I'll test the Process monitor thing you suggested once i have a little more time on my computer, but thank you for the suggestion; very helpful :)
